# Am I using NAT correctly on my Cisco ASA 5505?

Tags: cisco, routing, nat

I'm attempting to forward remote desktop (3389) to a PC inside my network.

I made it work, but I'm curious if I'm doing it right.  It doesn't seem natural to me.  I'm using ASDM visual setup.

The NAT rule itself is on the INSIDE interface.  The "original" is "internal_ip:3389" and the "translated" is "external_ip:3389".

Isn't the "original" (incoming packets from internet) going to "external_ip:3389"?  The "translated" should be the internal PC.  Basically the flip-flop of what I said above.

But if I create the NAT rule on the OUTSIDE interface like such, it doesn't work.

Shouldn't it work on either since NAT and UN-NAT?

Comment: a) What software version? b) include the relevant parts of the config.

Answer (score 2):

Given what you said, I think you are forgetting to consider the direction of traffic.  Lets start with a high level view of what a TCP connection looks like, then we'll talk about how it applies to NAT.

Let's assume my computer has the IP 10.1.1.1, and I am speaking to a server with the IP 3.3.3.3.  Let's also say that I am making a WEB/HTTP request, which runs on TCP port 80.  On the wire, the picket will have these attributes:

```
Source IP       : 10.1.1.1
Source Port     : 1111 (randomly chosen)
Destination IP  : 3.3.3.3
Destination Port: 80
```

When this packet makes it to the target server, and that server generates a response, the Source and Destination will be flipped.  That return traffic will therefore have the following attributes:

```
Source IP       : 3.3.3.3
Source Port     : 80
Destination IP  : 10.1.1.1
Destination Port: 1111
```

With that established, lets see how NAT affects this packet.  In particular, notice that the Source IP is a Private IP, and therefore must be NAT'ed when speaking on the internet.

What we would want, then, is for NAT to **change the Source IP on the Outbound traffic** and **change the Destination IP on the Return traffic**.  If NAT were to change the Destination IP on Outbound traffic or the Source on the Return traffic, the communication would never work.

---

Now in your particular case, you want inbound traffic *destined to your public IP address* to be forwarded through your NAT device to a particular host on your internal network.  So using the packet attributes above, you want a packet that looks like this to be NATed:

```
Source IP       : 9.9.9.9       (some IP address out there on the internet)
Source Port     : 9999          (randomly chosen)
Destination IP  : 2.2.2.2       (your External_IP)
Destination Port: 3389          (Remote Desktop Port)
```

And you want it to be NAT'ed to the following:

```
Source IP       : 9.9.9.9       (unchanged)
Source Port     : 9999          (unchanged)
Destination IP  : 192.168.0.20  (your Internal_IP)
Destination Port: 3389          (Remote Desktop Port)
```

Notice, you are intending to change the **destination IP**, and not the **source**.  But remember, what we are looking at here is the attributes for the incoming packet, *not those of the return traffic*.  If we were to map out the Return traffic, we would end up with the following:

```
Source IP       : 192.168.0.20  (your Internal_IP)
Source Port     : 3389          (Remote Desktop Port)  
Destination IP  : 9.9.9.9       (unchanged)
Destination Port: 9999          (unchanged)
```

**On the *Return traffic*, you are intending to NAT the *Source***.

---

And now, we can finally get back to your original question:

> Isn't the "original" (incoming packets from internet) going to
>   "external_ip:3389"? The "translated" should be the internal PC.
>   Basically the flip-flop of what I said above.
>
> But if I create the NAT rule on the OUTSIDE interface like such, it
>   doesn't work.
>
> Shouldn't it work on either since NAT and UN-NAT?

You're firewall is being told to NAT the **Source** from `internal_ip:3389` to `external_ip:3389`.  This is only the Source when the traffic is arriving on your Firewall's Inside interface -- which is to say, when your Firewall is seeing the **return traffic** of the RDP connection.

When you create the NAT rule on the OUTSIDE interface, it is **still looking at the Source** of the packet -- which is why the connection doesn't work, because you don't actually want to change the Source of the incoming packet, you want to change the destination.

By configuring the NAT on the INSIDE interface, you are telling your Firewall that when the Source IP:Port is `internal_:3389`, change it to `external_ip:3389`.  Lucky for you, your Firewall is automatically doing the inverse:  changing the Destination IP:Port from `external_ip:3389` to `internal_ip:3389` when it sees it on the Outside interface.

And lastly, as you've already found out, No, the NAT statement does not work when configured on either interface.  The particular NAT statement is looking specifically at the Source, and therefore must be configured from the perspective of when the Source needs to be changed.  If you configure it from the Outside interface, the changing the Source will not permit the traffic to get through your NAT and to your internal host.

Comment: Nice explanation! :)